# NServiceBus Exception and Error Queue

Tags: nservicebus

I'm a newbie in NServiceBus.
I have a question regarding Error Queue. 
In my IHandleMessages class , there is an exception thrown.
However, the message is not sent to Error Queue.
There is no exception information in log file. 
Even when I declare a try catch block, the exception seems not to be caught by the try catch block
Can anybody help me to clarify the error queue and exception handling in NserviceBus ? 
Thanks

Comment: Include your configuration and initialization code.

Comment: Try this http://www.nservicebus.com/faq/ExceptionHandling.aspx for more information.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the message is being retried and succeeding on a secondary attempt  http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/errors/automatic-retries